# create a Google Sheets FILTER/SEARCH formula with Apps Script using "or" logic

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

example sheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Sqt7_Ev9iagbE9CZT1F2lAUJqc1fX4WfbyaOBGEfqyQ/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks to a response to a previous question, I have Apps Script automatically updating formulas in Google Sheets when keywords are entered into input cells for a resources database. Currently, the formulas work with "and" logic (i.e., results must meet all conditions).

```
=FILTER(resources!B2:B,SEARCH(B2,resources!J2:J),SEARCH(B3,resources!K2:K))
```

Is there a formula using multiple SEARCH formulas as conditions within a FILTER formula using "or" logic (i.e., at least one of the conditions is met)?

I tried adding outer braces to the conditions and using "+" but it returns the same results.

```
=FILTER(resources!B2:B,(SEARCH(B2,resources!J2:J))+(SEARCH(B3,resources!K2:K)))
```

If so, how what script could be added to return the formula? My hope is to have a cell with data validation for AND & OR that will be used as a reference for an IF statement to determine which end formulas are set into the sheet. This is the current working code that uses "and" logic.

```js
// global variables
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const fcSheet = ss.getSheetByName('filterCode');
  const fcOption = fcSheet.getRange('B1').getValue();
  const fcInput = fcSheet.getRange('B2:B5').getValues();
const frSheet = ss.getSheetByName('resources');

var fcTabs = ['filterCode'];
var frTabs = ['resources']


// set simpleFilter formulas on edit
function onEdit(e) {
  var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();

  if (fcTabs.indexOf(activeSheet.getName()) !== -1 &&
    e.range.columnStart == 2 &&
    e.range.columnEnd == 2 &&
    e.range.rowStart >= 2 &&
    e.range.rowEnd <= 6) {
    var cell = e.range;

    if (ss.getActiveSheet().getRange("B2").getValue() != "") {
      var b2 = 'SEARCH(B2,resources!J2:J)'
    }
    else { var b2 = "" }

    if (ss.getActiveSheet().getRange("B3").getValue() != "") {
      var b3 = 'SEARCH(B3,resources!K2:K)'
    }
    else { var b3 = "" }

    if (ss.getActiveSheet().getRange("B4").getValue() != "") {
      var b4 = 'SEARCH(B4,resources!L2:L)'
    }
    else { var b4 = "" }

    if (ss.getActiveSheet().getRange("B5").getValue() != "") {
      var b5 = 'SEARCH(B5,resources!M2:M)'
    }
    else { var b5 = "" }

     if (ss.getActiveSheet().getRange("B6").getValue() != "") {
      var b6 = 'SEARCH(B6,resources!Q2:Q)'
    }
    else { var b6 = "" }

    if (b2 == '' && b3 == '' && b4 == '' && b5 == '' && b6 == '') {
      fcSheet.getRange(['C2']).setValue(' ⭠ set at least one search key');
      fcSheet.getRange(['A8:C8']).clearContent()
    }

    else {
      var fcInputList = [b2, b3, b4, b5, b6]
      var concatenated = fcInputList.filter(Boolean).join(',');
      fcSheet.getRange(['A8:C8']).setFormulas([['=FILTER(resources!B2:B,' + concatenated + ')', '=FILTER(resources!H2:H,' + concatenated + ')', '=FILTER(resources!I2:I,' + concatenated + ')']]);
      fcSheet.getRange(['C2']).clearContent();
    }
  }
}
```

updated code attempting to use separate simpleAnd and simpleOr functions based on C6.

```js
// global variables
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const fcSheet = ss.getSheetByName('filterCode');
  const fcOption = fcSheet.getRange('B1').getValue();
  const fcInput = fcSheet.getRange('B2:B5').getValues();
const frSheet = ss.getSheetByName('resources');

var fcTabs = ['filterCode'];
var frTabs = ['resources']


// set simpleFilter formulas on edit
function onEdit(e) {
  var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();

  if (fcTabs.indexOf(activeSheet.getName()) !== -1 && 
        e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.columnEnd == 2 &&
        e.range.rowStart >= 2 && e.range.rowEnd <= 6) {
    var cell = e.range;
    if (fcTabs.indexOf(activeSheet.getName()) !== -1 &&
    e.range.columnStart == 2 &&
    e.range.columnEnd == 2 &&
    e.range.rowStart >= 2 &&
    e.range.rowEnd <= 6 ) {
    var cell = e.range;
      if (fcSheet.getRange('C6') == 'OR') {
      simpleOr();
      }
    else simpleAnd();
    }
  }
}

function simpleAnd() {
  if (ss.getActiveSheet().getRange("B2").getValue() != "") {
    var b2 = 'SEARCH(B2,resources!J2:J)'
    }
    else { var b2 = "" }

    if (ss.getActiveSheet().getRange("B3").getValue() != "") {
      var b3 = 'SEARCH(B3,resources!K2:K)'
    }
    else { var b3 = "" }

    if (ss.getActiveSheet().getRange("B4").getValue() != "") {
      var b4 = 'SEARCH(B4,resources!L2:L)'
    }
    else { var b4 = "" }

    if (ss.getActiveSheet().getRange("B5").getValue() != "") {
      var b5 = 'SEARCH(B5,resources!M2:M)'
    }
    else { var b5 = "" }

     if (ss.getActiveSheet().getRange("B6").getValue() != "") {
      var b6 = 'SEARCH(B6,resources!Q2:Q)'
    }
    else { var b6 = "" }

    if (b2 == '' && b3 == '' && b4 == '' && b5 == '' && b6 == '') {
      fcSheet.getRange(['C2']).setValue(' ⭠ set at least one search key');
      fcSheet.getRange(['A8:C8']).clearContent()
    }

    else {
      var fcInputList = [b2, b3, b4, b5, b6]
      var concatenated = fcInputList.filter(Boolean).join(',');
      fcSheet.getRange(['A8:C8']).setFormulas([['=FILTER(resources!B2:B,' + concatenated + ')', '=FILTER(resources!H2:H,' + concatenated + ')', '=FILTER(resources!I2:I,' + concatenated + ')']]);
      fcSheet.getRange(['C2']).clearContent();
  }
}


function simpleOr() {
const activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const rangeReferences = [ // Attach input cells to columns
      { source: "B2", column: "J" },
      { source: "B3", column: "K" },
      { source: "B4", column: "L" },
      { source: "B5", column: "M" },
      { source: "B6", column: "Q" }
    ];
    let fcInputList = rangeReferences.map(reference => { // Loop through input cells
      const ref = reference.source;
      const col = reference.column;
      if (activeSheet.getRange(ref).getValue() != "") {
        return col + "='\"&" + ref + "&\"'"; // Build formula: eg. K='"&B3&"'
      } else return '';
    });
    const c2 = fcSheet.getRange('C2');
    if (fcInputList.every(input => input == "")) {
      c2.setValue(' ⭠ set at least one search key');
      fcSheet.getRange(['A8:C8']).clearContent()
    } else {
      fcInputList = fcInputList.filter(Boolean);
      const formula = '=QUERY(resources!B2:P26, "SELECT B,H,I WHERE ' + fcInputList.join(" OR ") + '")'; // Build rest of formula
      fcSheet.getRange("A8").setFormula(formula);
      c2.clearContent();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, free of sensitive information, clearly indicating the desired outcome?

Comment: @Iamblichus - thanks for your comment; post has been updated with a simplified spreadsheet and code.

Comment: Hi, I posted an answer. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Formula - use QUERY:

You could use the [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) function instead, with the [`where`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#where)
 and the logical operator `or`. For example, if `B2`, `B3` and `B5` were filled up, your formula in `A8` could be:

```
=QUERY(resources!B2:P26, "SELECT B,H,I WHERE J='"&B2&"' OR K='"&B3&"' OR M='"&B5&"'")
```

As you can see, a good thing about this formula is that you only need to call it once for all three output columns.

#### Update:

Interestingly, replacing `OR` with `AND` will result in a formula that uses the `and` operator instead, as you want. You'd just need to check whether the corresponding cell (`C6`) has the value `AND` or `NOT`, and use that information when building the formula:

```
=QUERY(resources!B2:P26, "SELECT B,H,I WHERE J='"&B2&"' AND K='"&B3&"' AND M='"&B5&"'")
```

#### Code snippet:

Then, in order to build and set this formula dynamically in your `onEdit` function, you could do the following:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const cell = e.range;
  const activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const OR_AND_CELL = "C6";
  if (fcTabs.indexOf(activeSheet.getName()) !== -1 && 
        ((e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.columnEnd == 2 &&
        e.range.rowStart >= 2 && e.range.rowEnd <= 6) ||
        cell.getA1Notation() === OR_AND_CELL)) {
    const OR_AND = activeSheet.getRange(OR_AND_CELL).getValue(); // Retrieve OR or AND
    const rangeReferences = [ // Attach input cells to columns
      { source: "B2", column: "J" },
      { source: "B3", column: "K" },
      { source: "B4", column: "L" },
      { source: "B5", column: "M" },
      { source: "B6", column: "P" }
    ];
    let fcInputList = rangeReferences.map(reference => { // Loop through input cells
      const ref = reference.source;
      const col = reference.column;
      if (activeSheet.getRange(ref).getValue() != "") {
        return col + "='\"&" + ref + "&\"'"; // Build formula: eg. K='"&B3&"'
      } else return '';
    });
    const c2 = fcSheet.getRange('C2');
    if (fcInputList.every(input => input == "")) {
      c2.setValue(' ⭠ set at least one search key');
      fcSheet.getRange(['A8:C8']).clearContent()
    } else {
      fcInputList = fcInputList.filter(Boolean);
      const formula = '=QUERY(resources!B2:P26, "SELECT B,H,I WHERE ' + fcInputList.join(" " + OR_AND + " ") + '")'; // Build rest of formula
      fcSheet.getRange("A8").setFormula(formula);
      c2.clearContent();
    }
  }
}
```

#### Example:

[image]

#### Note:

- You will notice I've simplified your code a bit, reducing the amount of repetition. For example `rangeReferences` is used to specify which cells (`B2...B6`) are connected to which columns (`J`,`K`,`L`, etc.). This way, you can execute the corresponding actions in a loop. I hope this is useful to you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was able to replace the script and use the QUERY. However, when I attempted to set the original script as one function (simpleAnd) and your new script as another (simpleOr) to be run based on whether cell C6 said AND or OR, I was unsuccessful. The simpleOr function was not used. additionally, when it would replace the simpleAnd, it could not overwrite the formulas in B8:C8. I feel like this could be resolved with a clear contents line. However, any thoughts on having the option to use either function based on a C6? Updating code in original post. @Iamblichus

Comment: @eirever Just change the `OR` to `AND` in the query formula, based on the value in `C6`. I updated the code correspondingly. Let me know if that works for you (in this case, since the `AND` formula would also only exist in `B8`, there would be no need to clear contents anyway).

Comment: Thanks again. The script is working and effectively uses the C6 AND/OR value to update the formula. While I really like the streamlined nature of QUERY, I found that it does not handle partial matches effectively, which the FILTER+SEARCH formula did. Do you have any thoughts on how partial matches may be possible?

Comment: @eirever Can you clarify what type of partial match you are referring to, maybe with some examples? I'd suggest you to create a new question in order to handle this.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I decided to troubleshoot on my own for a while. I was able to obtain my desired result by replacing the "=" with "contains" in the fcInput return line of code. Thanks for all your help!